# Query CSV File/general database questions

Tags: csv

OK so I'm kinda new to databases in general. I understand the basic theory behind them and have knocked up the odd Access DB here and there.

One thing I'm struggling to learn about is the specifics of how e.g. an SQL query accesses a database.

So say you have a scenario where there's a database on a LAN server (let's say it's MS Access for arguments sake). You run some SQL query or other on it from a client machine. Does the client machine have to download the entire database to run said query (even if the result of the query is just one line)? Or does it somehow manage to get just the data it wants to come down the ol' CAT5? Does the server have to be running anything to do that? Can't quite understand how the client could get JUST the query results without the server having to do some of the work...

I'm seeing two conflicting stories on this matter when googling stuff.

And so this follows on the next question (which may already be answered): if you CAN query a DB without having to get the whole damn thing, and without the server running any other software, can the same be done with a CSV? If not, why not?

Reason I ask is I'm developing an app for a mobile device that needs to talk to a db or CSV file of some kind, and it'll be updating records at a pretty high rate (barcode scanning), so don't want the network to grind to a halt (it's a slow bag of [insert relevant insult] as it is). The less data travelling from device to server, the better.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The various SQL servers are just that: a server. It's a program that listens for client queries and sends back a response. It is more than just its data.

A CSV file, or "flat file" is just data. There is no way for it to respond to a query by itself.

So, when you are on a network, your query is sent to the server, which does the work of finding the appropriate results. When you open a flat file, you're using the network and/or file system to read/write the entire file.

**Edit** to add a note about your specific usage. You'll probably want to use a database engine, as the queries are going to be the least amount of network traffic. For example, when you scan a barcode, your query may be as simple as the following text:

```
INSERT INTO barcode_table ('code', 'scan_date', 'user') VALUES ('1234567890', '2011-01-24 12:00:00', '1');
```

The above string is handled by the database engine and the code (along with whatever relevant support data) is stored. No need for your application to open a file, append data to it, and close it. The latter becomes very slow once files get to a large size, and concurrency can become a problem with many users accessing it.

If your application needs to display some data to your user, it would request specific information the same way, and the server would generate the relevant results. So, imagine a scenario in which the user wants a list of products that match some filter. If your products were books, suppose the user requested a list by a specific author:

```
SELECT products.title, barcode_table.code
FROM products, barcode_table
WHERE products.author = 'Anders Hejlsberg'
ORDER BY products.title ASC;
```

In this example, only those product titles and their barcodes are sent from the server to the mobile application.

Hopefully these examples help make a case for using a structure database engine of some kind, rather than using a flat file. The specific flavor and implementation of database, however, is another question unto itself.

Comment: I get how to use SQL, but thanks for the post anyway, it's made things a bit more solid in my head.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, relational databases are stored on a remote server, and you access them via a client interface.  Each database vendor has software that you'd install on your remote computer that would allow you to access the database on a server.  The entire DB is not sent back to the client when a query is executed, although it can send very large result sets if you are not careful about how to structure your query.  Generally speaking the flow is like this:

- A database server listens for clients to connect
- A client connects and issues a SQL
  command to the database
- The database builds a query plan to
  figure out how to get the result
- The plan is executed and the results
  are sent back to the client.

CSV is simply a file format, not a fully functional platform like a relational database.

Comment: Yeah this seems to be what I thought the case was. So in the case of a .mdb file (Access) on a server (the server ain't running anything, just literally hosting the file), in THAT scenario does the client download the whole file? Thanks

Comment: I guess the answer is no. The Access file is organized in pages, so that reading the table (or form) definitions, retrieving part of the index, or part of the data, only require random-accessing a part of the MDB file.

Comment: Ah ok. I'm guessing this can't be accomplished with anything other than a proper database then? I guess the real question I'm asking is whether I can access a CSV like that.

Comment: Since a CSV file is extremely easy to parse, why not parse the file into a real relational database and work with it that way?

Comment: I suppose the question really is WHICH RDB...SQL Server seems a bit excessive (plus I have no idea how to use it) and Access is outta the window as mentioned. What does that leave?

Comment: nvm, have bit the bullet and installed SQL Server